# XQuery: update insert attribute failed

Tags: xquery, basex

test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<breakfast_menu>
<food>
  <name>French Toast aaa</name>
  <price>$5.95</price>
  <description>Our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
  <calories>650</calories>
</food>
<food>
  <name>French Toast</name>
  <price>$4.50</price>
  <description>Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread</description>
  <calories>600</calories>
</food>
<food>
  <name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>
  <price>$6.95</price>
  <description>Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns</description>
  <calories>950</calories>
</food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

test.xqy:

```
for $x in doc('test.xml')//*
return update insert attribute id {'abcd'} into $x
```

For each XML markup I add a new attribute.
The xqy file is pretty simple. And I got:

```
[XPST0003] Unexpected end of query: 'insert attribut...'.
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're having two issues here:

- misuse of the `update` statement and
- missing `node` keyword.

The BaseX-specific [`update` statement is only meant to be used with the `copy`/`modify` construct](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Updates#update); you don't need it here. Then, the operator for inserting any kinds of nodes is always `insert node $node [positional clause] into $target` with an optional `[positional clause]`. Instead of a node variable `$node`, you can of course also use a node constructor like `attribute id {'abcd'}`.

The correct query is:

```
for $x in doc('test.xml')//*
return insert node attribute id {'abcd'} into $x
```

Comment: HI Erat, how can we define position like before or after  here for attribute .e,g, if we have to insert  attribute 'id' before attribute 'author'